# Login system with roles asp.net 4.5.2 not MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication

I need to write application (asp.net), where are 2 roles (admin, user). Sometime I wrote simple, when was asp.net 2.0. I use VS Express 2015.
I create New Project -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Web, next ASP.NET application. In the next window Webforms and OK.
In Solution Explorer I have Account folder and inside them I have files for servicing users. After I run app. tables in database were created.
What I need to do, to add roles to this system? (Sometime was Administer Website)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/identity.

This identity management system is based on Entity Framework and can be setup automatically using some simple powershell commands in visual studio.